# Amplifying signal with op-amp 741 doesn't work

Tags: operational-amplifier, 741-opamp

I have a 500 Hz sine wave with amplitude 1V, and I need to amplify this signal 3 times, i.e. the required amplitude is 3V.

I tried to connect the circuit two times as shown below, using gain 3/1, which is 3 as required, and 3k/1k, which is also 3 as required. However, the output is not as required, the signal is just doubled in amplitude not tripled.

[image: 1]

The output is:
[image: 2]

Comment: Not sure if it causes your problem, but you should definitely have ground connected in the middle of the op-amp power supply

Comment: 6V between ground and pin 7 and -6V between ground and pin 4. The simulator probably doesn't know whether it's 12V and 0V, or 0V and -12V, or 1000V and 1012V. A common simulation mistake.

Comment: look up "split-rail power supply"

Comment: It's not your problem here, but I have to point it out: the 741 is *extremely* obsolete and should never be used. There are much better op amps out there, even for the same price.

Comment: @M-125 Yeah, use the LM358. It's newer and the specs are better but it's still dirt cheap. The most important spec difference is that it can output almost at its negative supply rail so if you have a unipolar supply (like +V and 0V) it can more properly output a 0V output. The 741 can only get to within 1 or 2V of the negative rail so you basically can't use it like that.

Comment: Certainly better. The 358 is probably good enough for a lot of applications.

Comment: I'm actually confused as to how you're getting a gain out of this at all, given that you have positive feedback. It should just be outputting a square wave--you might be driving the 741 into phase reversal or something, I haven't looked into what that would do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your opamps are wired up as comparators with hysteresis (positive feedback), not as finite gain amplifiers (negative feedback). And your resistors are way too small for the op amp to drive properly. You should be getting square waves and not what you are currently seeing.

So your fundamental circuit isn't correct for your intention.

If you are trying to amplify without inversion then you need the non-inverting amplifier circuit. If you just take an inverting amp circuit and swap the opamp inputs it doesn't produce the non-inverting amp. It just produces a comparator with hysteresis.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Well, doesn't change what the problem is.

Comment: Oh, yeah also right. I wasn't paying enough attention. But then you have a comparator. I don't think your circuit is doign what you think it is. The resistances are way too small.

Comment: @M-125 Not the same thing because you are referencing your input to 0V but you have set the negative supply to 0V. So your signal is not referenced mid supply but it's trying to go negative and has nowhere left to go. For example, you can reference your input signal to 0V and give the opamp +12V and -12V supply so that an output below the reference can be produed if the output needs to go below it.. Or you can give it a +12V and 0V supply but then you must reference your signal at 6V so the output can below the reference.

Comment: @M-125 changing inverting to non-inverting is not as simple as swapping + and -

Comment: The opamp doesn't really care to be honest since voltage is just a difference, but it matters where your signal is biased between the power supply rails relative to that. Since +12V and -12V is the same as 24V and 0V as far as the opamp is concerned but your signal needs to be biased at the appropriate point in that range to allow positive and negative swing should it be necessary for your application. If the input is referenced at the very edge, it doesn't have enough room to swing in that direction. You should understand this even though it's not the problem in your current circuit.

Comment: What part did you not understand? The bipolar voltage rail thing in the comments? Or the non-inverting amp thing in my edited answer?

Comment: @M-125 Think like this. An opamp only have two power supply terminals so it only knows the voltage between two points. So if I have a building and can only measure the height difference between two points I can't tell the difference between a building with 2nd Floor, Ground Level, and Basement, or a building with 3rd floor, 2nd floor and ground level because if I measure I always get 3 floors. So the opamp doesn't care if it's 12V and -12V or 24V and 0V. It's the same as far as it's concerned.

Comment: But input signal's reference is like starting one one of the floors. If your application and circuit require you to go one floor down and you start in basement in the building with the basement, you can't go anywhere. Likewise, if you start on the ground floor in the building with no basement you also have nowhere to go. So you can either change the building (the power supply rails) or change the floor you start on (bias your input to be mid-supply, whatever it happens to be).

Comment: Yes that link is the non-inverting amp. There is also a gain equation you can look up.

Comment: @M-125 Yes. So if you have an inverting amp like that and feed it a positive input it will try and produce an output on the low-side of GND, which it can't without a supply more negative than GND. But your circuit as posted is neither an inverting amp nor a noninvertgin amp so the stuff I said isn't the problem in your circuit (it's just I misread what your circuit was initially).

Comment: @M-125 If you have an input signal that needs to "swing negative" or an output that needs to swing negative but your opamp is only powered with a single-ended supply such as 5V and 0V then you need to bias your input signal so that the signal is referenced at mid-supply (2.5V) and also modify your amplifier so it amplifies relative to that mid-supply voltage. So then instead of your input and output trying to swing above and below 0V, your input and output now swing above and below 2.5V.

Comment: For non-inverting amp configuration, the voltage  on the inverting terminal is what the amplifier will amplify the input signal against. Biasing your input signal so it swings around something other than 0V before you feed it to the non-inverting amp circuit is a separate issue.

Comment: This has gone on too far off track. If you have additional questions make a separate question, multiple if necessary for the different proper circuit configurations with the specific modification you have in mind. Because as is, the circuit in your question doesn't even match your intent and doesn't even work properly for what it is wired as.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a correct way to connect the parts. I've used +/-15V supplies. It will work down to +/-6V but output swing will be limited.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCmk4b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the gain is -3.

[image]

To do a gain of +3 you will need a different configuration *and* a different resistor ratio.

Comment: @M-125 Notice that the feedback is connected to the *inverting* input, not the non-inverting input as you have it. If the feedback is on the non-inverting input, that's (to gloss over some unusual cases that aren't relevant here) positive feedback, which turns the amplifier into a comparator with hysteresis instead of an amplifier. Although I'm pretty sure the 741 isn't that good to use as a comparator.

Comment: @M-125 But the way you've connected this is as a comparator, not as a non-inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 2):

If the output of the opamp is supposed to have the same polarity as the input signal, the input signal needs to be connected to the positive input.  The feedback has to be on the negative input either way.  If you want an amplification by a factor of 3, the feedback needs to be divided by 3, so you'd use a voltage divider towards ground (2k2 and 1k1, for example).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCef2E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>